# Using jquery to get specific data from json and display in html

Tags: jquery, json, variables, compare

I'm making a website where the main container is split up into two 50% halves. On the left are thumbnails and on the right there's a detailed view of the clicked thumbnail. The detailed view is stored in json. It's the first time i'm writing "my own" jquery and could use a bit of help!

This is what i have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var collectie = $.getJSON( "js/collectie.json", function() {
    console.log( "Got collection" );
    console.log(collectie);
})

$( "#collectie li" ).click(function(){

        console.log("click detected");

    var thumb_id = $(this).data("id");

        console.log(thumb_id);

    var stoel_id = $(collectie).data(thumb_id);

        console.log(stoel_id);


});

});
```

I still have to make the part where it puts the data into the html, but first i would like to make sure i get the correct data in a var or something.
A friend told me i should store the json in a var first, so it doesn't have to load on each click event. Then i tried to store the correct data in stoel_id by selecting the data from collectie that matches thumb_id. 
Now this is where i get lost. I know my syntax is probably horrid but i tried to put it together using the 30+ open tabs of information i found.

So what i want to do is:

1. load json (done)
2. put a click event checker on the thumbnails (done)
3. get thumb_id from html (done)
4. get the data corresponding to thumb_id from the json (need help!)
5. put that data into html (i think i can do this)

This is the JSON i'm using:

```
{
"stoelen":
    [
        {"title": "Stoel1", "image": "/images/stoelen/1.png", "description": "Hier komt de beschrijving van de eerste foto", "secondaryimage": "/images/grid/7.png"},
        {"title": "Stoel2", "image": "/images/stoelen/2.png", "description": "Hier komt de beschrijving van de tweede foto", "secondaryimage": "/images/grid/6.png"},
        {"title": "Hogestoel1", "image": "/images/stoelen/1.png", "description": "Hier komt de beschrijving van de eerste foto", "secondaryimage": "/images/grid/7.png"},
        {"title": "Hogestoel2", "image": "/images/stoelen/2.png", "description": "Hier komt de beschrijving van de tweede foto", "secondaryimage": "/images/grid/6.png"}
    ]
}
```

Please don't hesitate asking for any extra information and thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

thumb_id is the contents of a data-id-tag in the html which is going to be the same as "title" in the json.
Clickable list items like this:

```
<ul>
        <li data-id="stoel1"><img src=""></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can You Explain About thumb_id ? is it 1.png/2.png?

Comment: It'd be helpful to see your markup for the clickable thumbnails - it sounds like you've got something along the lines of `<li data-id="1">...</li>`, is that correct?

Comment: thumb_id is going to be the same as "title" in the json.
And the markup for the clickable thumbnails is correct.

Edited the question to include this.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
for(i=0;i<collectie.stoelen.length;i++)
{
   var  jsonid= collectie.stoelen[i].title;
    if(jsonid===thumb_id)
       {
           $(this).find('img').attr('src',collectie.stoelen[i].image);

       }
}
```

Comment: Console returns "TypeError: collectie.stoelen is undefined" on line 13 which is the start of your code. I also tried to put "stoelen" between squared brackets as i figured it's an array but that also does not work.

Comment: I think since the json is stored in a var you don't need to do "collectie.stoelen.length", but can just do "collectie.length". Still doesn't work though :).

Answer (score 0):

Try (this pattern)

```
var request = function (q) {
    var url = "js/collectie.json";
    var el = arguments[0];
    var q = $.makeArray($(arguments[0]).data("id"));
    var dfd = new $.Deferred();
    var results = [];
    request._notify = function(args) {
      return $.each(arguments, function(k, v) {
        console.log(v)
      });
    };
    $.getJSON(url
    , function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
        console.log("Got collection", data, q[0]);
        $.each((data[Object.keys(data)]), function (k, v) {
            if (String(v["title"]).toLowerCase() === q[0]) {
                results.push(v);
                dfd.notify(["'" + q[0] + "'" 
                            + " found in collection"
                            , results[0]
                            , $(".clicked").size() + 1]);
                dfd.resolve([results[0]
                             , el
                             , q[0]
                             , $(el)
                             .siblings("li").length + 1])
            };
        });
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      dfd.reject([textStatus, errorThrown]);
    });
    return dfd.promise()
};

    $("ul")
    .find("li")
    .attr("title", "click")
    .css({
        "width": "100%",
        "margin": "4px",
        "list-style": "none"
    })
    .on("click", function (e) {
    request($(e.target).not("li") 
            ? $(e.target).closest("li") 
            : $(e.target))
        .then(function (data) {
        var results = data[0];
        $(data[1])
            .addClass("clicked")
            .html(function (i, o) {
            return o.indexOf(results["description"]) != -1 
            ? o 
            : o + results["description"]
            })
            .find("img")
            .attr("src", results["image"]);
        if ($(".clicked").size() === data[3]) {
            console.log($(".clicked").size() 
                        + " items loaded from collection, complete.");
            $(".clicked").off("click");
        };
        }, function (error) {
             request._notify.apply($, error);
        }, function (progress) {
             request._notify.apply($, progress);  
        });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/txkpagyz/

Comment: I'm sorry, should have closed this question. An IRL friend helped me finish it, i'll post the javascript i used in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is the javascript/jquery i used for it to work, works perfect now. Thanks for all the input!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$.getJSON( "js/collectie.json", function(data) {
    jsoncollectie = data;
})

$( "#collectie li" ).click(function(){

    console.log("click detected");
    var thumb_id = $(this).data("id");
    console.log(thumb_id);
    console.log(jsoncollectie);

    for(var i = 0; i < jsoncollectie.stoelen.length; i++){

        if(jsoncollectie.stoelen[i].title == thumb_id){
            $("#detailimage").attr('src', jsoncollectie.stoelen[i].image);
            console.log(jsoncollectie.stoelen[i]);
        }   

    }

});

function getLengthObject(o){
    var key, count = 0;

    for(key in o) {
        if(o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        count++;
        }
    }

    return count;

}

});
```